# Using Grunt for Sass and Autoprefixer. Need help to set up my config file

Tags: javascript, css, sass, autoprefixer

I'm trying to setup my gruntconfig.js and while the tasks are running without errors on terminal, Autoprefixer and Grunt's Watch are not working at all.
Am I doing something wrong?
BTW can I run Saas and Autoprefixer together?

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

// configures task(s)
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

sass: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      outputStyle: 'expanded'
    },
    files: {
      'css/style.css' : 'src/scss/main.scss.css'
    }
  }
},

watch: {
    css: {
      files: 'src/scss/main.scss.css',
      tasks: ['sass', 'autoprefixer']
    }
},

    autoprefixer: {
  files: {
    'css/style.css': 'src/scss/main.scss.css'
  }
}

});

// Load the Plugins
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-autoprefixer');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');


// Register Task(s)
grunt.registerTask('default', ['autoprefixer', 'sass'] );

};
```

And here's my directory structure

```
assets

css
    style.css
    normalize.css

fonts

gruntfile.js

img

index.html

js

node_modules

package.json

src
    design
    js
    scss
        main.scss
```

It's my 1st time doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. I started using Codekit.
Waaaay better!